# Repository pattern with interchangeable data access

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, repository

I've just read about the repository pattern in c#. It will provide an interchangeable layer for how the actual data is accessed. That's great. However, consider the following:

I have an XmlPersonRepository which will fetch XML data from a file and return it as a c# object (Person.cs POCO). Now I want the physical source of the XML data to be interchangeable too. Originally, it comes from a file, but it can also come from a web server or from a resource string. How would I implement this in the most reusable way? I don't want to write something like XmlPersonFromFileRepository and a XmlPersonFromWebRepository, because it would mean code duplication. It would duplicate the code for converting the raw XML data into a c# object, but this code stays the same, no matter if i fetch XML from a file or from a web service. So it's redundant to have the conversion code in both classes.

So in a nutshell, I want to have two abstraction layers: One layer which fetches the psysical XML data from whatever source, and another layer which converts this data into c# objects. Both should be interchangeable.

How can I implement this? And please tell me if this is a good idea or not, am I on the right track?

Comment: DEpendency injection is your friend!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. You just worded it in your question.

You have two problems to solve:

- Get XML data from a source
- Convert XML data to C# Object

To implement the first problem:
 - IXmlDataGetter, an interface getting a single XML data from a source.

```
    public interface IXmlDataGetter {
      XmlData GetData(XmlDataName name);
    }
```

"XmlData" should be either a byte[] or a Stream (Because XML contains metadata with regards to the encoding of data, I think it should be kept at byte level) or be a DOM Tree (like XmlNode). You choose the solution that fits you best.

"XmlDataName" is the way you identify a your stored data. Data has a name, however complex it may be. It may be just the string "PERSON" and the integer 25, being the id. The name of the data for the person with ID 25 may be the pair ("PERSON", 25).

This interface, can be implemented  for DB:

```
    public class DBXmlDataGetter : IXmlDataGetter {
      XmlData GetData(XmlDataName name) {
        return ResultOfQuery("SELECT xml_text FROM " + name.first /* PERSON */ + " WHERE ID=" + name.second  /* 25 */); 
      }
    }
```

This interface can also be implemented for a file:

```
    public class FileXmlDataGetter : IXmlDataGetter {
      XmlData GetData(XmlDataName name) {
        return ContentsOfFile(name.first /* PERSON */ + "_" + name.second /* 25 */ + ".xml"); 
      }
    }
```

Of course "ResultOfQuery" and "ContentsOfFile" are just names of things I leave it to you to solve. And for the Web, build your URL from your XmlDataName the same way.

Now. Second problem, converting XML to C# object. You may use an XMLDeserializer, or parse the data with an XMLReader and build your object explicitly. You just have to create a class that does te job and takes the appropriate strategy as a constructor parameter:

```
    public class XmlPersonRepository {
      private readonly IXmlDataGetter _getter;

      public PersonFetcher(IXmlDataGetter getter) {
        _getter = getter;
      }

      Person GetFromId(int id) {
        var xmlData = _getter.GetData(new XmlDataName("PERSON", id));
        return ConvertToPerson(xmlData); 
      }
    }
```

I won't get into the philosophical questions of IoC/Dependency injection here, but this is the basic pattern. The class that does the conversion just does the conversion. All it needs to perform the use case from end to end gets "injected" from "above".

You separated the responsibilities, now you're free to get your XML data from a user copy/paste in a textbox if you wish.

Comment: Thanks for this great and easy to understand example. I already started reading about dependency injection, it's great, but I feel it doesn't solve my initial question on how to actually split reponsibility for the two steps (1. get raw data, 2. convert data) - which you just did by providing the code examples. Awesome, thanks again!

Comment: This is just one example, but reading your question again, it does not answer it completely. If you want BOTH to be interchangeable, you have to abstract away the "ConvertToPerson" method into an IXmlToPersonConverter interface with a single method, then inject it into the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

As said, check what Dependency Injection/Ioc is and have a look to some of the frameworks out there (like Ninject, Autofac etc).
In a nutshell you should create an interface `IXmlPersonRepository` that defines your methods and then implement it on all the different classes that will provide you the xml like

- XmlFilePersonRepository : IXmlPersonRepository
- XmlDBPersonRepository : IXmlPersonRepository

and so on.

You will then use the interface IXmlPersonRepository to do your calls. The DI bit will be responsible of the concrete implementation of your interface and it will be easy to swap between db, file etc.

Comment: Thank you, I will check out Dependency Injection. Also thanks for your hint regarding IXmlPersonRepository.